# Aligning the widths of DropdownList and TextBox in a table

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox, alignment, css-tables

I have a table with 1 column. In this column, there are either rows with a textbox or with a dropdownlist. What I want now is that these controls have the same width. So I set the Width of the controls to 100%. The result however is that the dropdownlists are like 5-10px shorter than the textboxes. 
I have tried setting:

```
Width="100%"
```

as well as:

```
style="width: 100%"
```

But no success there. In the Visual Studio designer, the width is correct for all controls. But in Firefox, Chrome or even IE, the dropdownlists are shorter.

Suggestions please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this work using `box-sizing`:

```
input, select, textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fthrd/)

Comment: Thank you, finally a solution to this CSS mess ;)